# Converting for-loop to a linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I like to think of myself as pretty good with LINQ, but every now and then I try to accomplish something that I just can't get to work.  I'd like to convert a `SPListItemCollection` to a dictionary so I can use the key to look up a value without the need for a LINQ query each time:

```
var formsConfigItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (SPListItem item in list.GetItems(query))
    formsConfigItems.Add(item.Title, (item["Value"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Value"].ToString()));
```

This works, but I was hoping to do it in a cleaner fashion, using LINQ.  (not a big deal but I like to use LINQ over for-loops whenever possible, although it's the same thing behind the scenes.

I tried to do something like this:

```
var formsConfigItems = (from SPListItem i in list.GetItems(query)
                        select new { i.Title, i["Value"].ToString() }).ToDictionary<string, string>(k=>k.Key, k=>k.Value);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  If I try to use a lambda expression on `list.GetItems(query)`, I'm not given the option to use `.Where` or any LINQ commands (which is weird because it is an `SPListCollection`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If I try to use a lambda expression on list.GetItems(query), I'm not given the option to use".   Does the return type implement IEnumerable<T>?  You many need to call list.GetItems(query).AsEnumerable() if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
var formsConfigItems = list.GetItems(query)
                           .Cast<SPListItem>()
                           .ToDictionary(item => item.Title, 
                                         item => Convert.ToString(item["Value"]));
```

To answer your queries:

> If I try to use a lambda expression on list.GetItems(query), I'm not
>   given the option to use .Where or any linq commands (which is weird
>   because it is an SPListCollection)

That's because [`SPListCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.aspx) is an "old-school" collection that implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`, so C# / LINQ (at compile-time anyway) can't tell what *type* of items it contains. The `Cast<SPListItem>()` call helps work around this issue - it turns an `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<T>`, allowing the type-algebra to work out at compile-time . Your `for` loop doesn't have this issue since you explicitly specify the type of the loop variable - the compiler inserts a cast on your behalf for each item in the sequence.

> I tried to do something like this (query expression).  But that
>   doesn't seem to work.

That's because you are not constructing the anonymous type instance correctly (property names can't be inferred for arbitrary expressions) and your lambda expression isn't quite right either (the property names you use don't match the property names of the anonymous type). Try this instead:

```
var formsConfigItems = (from SPListItem i in list.GetItems(query)
                        select new 
                        { 
                            i.Title, 
                            Value = Convert.ToString(i["Value"])
                        }).ToDictionary(a => a.Title, a => a.Value);
```

Comment: @Joe: Cheers, I've upvoted yours because of the extra details.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  This has been very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Ani's got the better solution IMO, but one other thing you're missing: Your LINQ statement is creating a collection of anonymous items, but you're not giving names to the properties in that anonymous class.

The `k=>k.Key` expression doesn't work, because it doesn't know what `Key` is - you've only defined `Title` (since you didn't give it a name, it borrowed the one from the object). The `Value` one can't be automatically figured out, so it would throw a compiler error.

To do it this way, you'd need to specifically declare the names:

```
new { Key = i.Title, Value = i["Value"].ToString() }
```